# Where do questions about IDE features / installation management go?

Tags: discussion

Is this an appropriate question for SO?

[Can I uninstall Visual Basic from Visual Studio 11 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596037/can-i-uninstall-vb-from-visual-studio-11-beta)

Comment: Er.. barely.  Who's going to care about this once the beta has finished?  Its more "too localized" than off topic.

Comment: @Won't - since when are questions about a <thing's> beta off topic?  CTP / Beta framework questions get asked all the time here

Comment: @Adam Rackis: He probably means "barely appropriate", not "barely on topic". I'll agree with him that it's localized though, as with all questions about beta software that eventually graduate to RTM.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: barely appropriate = barely on topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That looks alright to me since questions about Visual Studio, as an IDE, have always been welcome on Stack Overflow. Our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) explicitly allows questions about IDEs on our site:

> if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: but its not really about an IDE feature as much as it is about how to uninstall part of an IDE. it just seems to fall into a grey area IMO.

Comment: @j_mcnally Nope, those sorts of issues are fine on SO as long as they are specifically for development tools.  Developers regularly encounter such issues, so it's relevant to the expertise of SO users.

Comment: Well, think about it: who else is in a better position to answer such a question than a MS developer? I suppose it wouldn't be *off* topic on Super User, but we're talking about development tools here; even if you asked it there they'll probably toss it back to us.

Comment: fair enough. just wanted to know what to do in the future i guess so that i am not wrongfully downvoting flagging things like this.